Batch Relink/Replace Textures from Different Directory
Short Version

I have 2 Folders, one with 2K textures and other with 4K Textures.
Blender currently uses textures from 4K folder, I want to switch to textures from 2K Folder.
Note that names and types(png/jpg) of files in both 2K folder and 4K folder are same, just resolution is different.

Detailed Version

I have imported a GLB file into blender.
I extracted the textures inbuilt in the GLB file using "File --> External Data --> Unpack Resources
All textures were 4K, I resized them to 2K while keeping the same filename of the 4K one. Saved them all to a separate folder named 2K
Now, In the glb imported into blender, I have multiple objects and materials and each material has it's own set of 4K image textures.

What I would like to do is to switch all or batch swith 4K image textures to the 2K ones as efficiently as possible

If the file names are all the same, and one set is in a folder like for example "4k_textures" and the others are in a folder "2k_textures", then rename the 4k folder to something different, like "4k_textures_old" or whatever. Next go to the File menu and choose External Data > Find Missing Files.

In the opening file dialogue box, navigate inside the "2k_textures" folder. You do not have to select a file. In the sidepanel (shortcut N) you could select Find All. This means, it will change the datapaths of all files (not only the 4k textures) to the 2k folder, if there are other files with the same names used in the scene. After choosing the folder, click the Find Missing Files button.

Using Find All would also make renaming the 4k folder redundant, as it would redirect all files to the new 2k folder, even though they were still to be found in the original path. However, as I said before, if there are other files in your scene in different folders which have namesakes in the 2k folder, they would also be redirected which you might not want.

Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much Gordon.
